# How to show the conditions of the following definitions for any given function (Fourier series):

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, piecewise-continuity

Can anyone explain to me, how to show the conditions of the following definitions for any given function:

$\text{Definition 1}:$

$
\text{let}\ \mathcal{C_{st}} \ \text{denote the set of those functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$},\text{that satisfies the following conditions:}
\\(1)\ f \ \text{is periodic with period} \  2\pi
\\(2)\ f \ \text{is piecewise continuous on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$}
\\(3)\ f \ \text{is normalized in its points of discontinuity, i.e.}
$
$$
f(x)=\frac{f(x_-)+f(x_+)}{2}
$$
at any point of discontinuity $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for $f$

$\text{Definition 2}:$

$\text{let}\ \mathcal{D_{st}} \ \text{denote the set of those functions $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$},\text{that satisfies the following conditions:}
\\(1)\ f \ \text{is periodic with period} \  2\pi
\\(2)\ f \ \text{is piecewise differentiable on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$}
\\(3)\ f \ \text{is normalized in its points of discontinuity, i.e.}
$
$$
f(x)=\frac{f(x_-)+f(x_+)}{2}
$$
at any point of discontinuity $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for $f$

Just to let you know $\mathcal{C}_{st}$ is a subspace of the vector space of all complex function on $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathcal{C}_{st}$ is a complex vector space, that have the following scalar product:
$$
\left( f,g\right):=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi {f(x) \overline{g(x)}} \ dx \ , f,g\in \mathcal{C}_{st}
$$
Where $\mathcal{D}_{st} \subseteq{\mathcal{C}_{st}}$

$f(x_-)=\lim_{y \rightarrow x_-}{f(y)}$ is the limit of the function from the left hand side.

$f(x_+)=\lim_{y \rightarrow x_+}{f(y)}$ is the limit of the function from the right hand side.

Definition 1 and 2 is pretty much the same except for condition number 2, and it could be very nice if someone could explain me how to show that a function is

1. Periodic with period $2\pi$
2. Piecewise **continuous** on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$
3. Piecewise **differentiable** on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$
4. Normalized in its points of discontinuity, i.e. $$f(x)=\frac{f(x_-)+f(x_+)}{2}$$ at any point of discontinuity $x\in \mathbb{R}$ for $f$

I really appreciate it and thanks in advance

Comment: Did you notice both definitions you gave are for $\;\mathcal C_{st}\;$ ? I think though that definition 2 is for $\;\mathcal D_{st}\;$

Comment: Is there any specific of the points that you have problems with? Do you have any examples of functions that you want to show the conditions for?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to show the conditions, if you know an example that can help me understand the conditions so that I can show the conditions for any given function, then I will like too see it.

Comment: If we have the function $f(x)=|x|$ on the open interval $(-\pi,\pi)$, will this satisfy the conditions for the definitions?